# vba cannot clear the word ContentControl content

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

The contentcontrol "contents cannot be edited" checkbox is unchecked, and I use code to set

```
LockContets = False
```

, but even so, there is still error "You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected"

the code is as follow:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim CC As ContentControl  
  For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
      Debug.Print CC.Type
      Debug.Print CC.Range.Text
      CC.LockContentControl = True
      CC.LockContents = False
      CC.Range.Text = ""    <--error here


  Next CC
End Sub
```

why will this happen? how to solve it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.text

Comment: No, range.text is available in Word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot clear the text from Dropdown List, CheckBox, or Picture Content Controls, since they don't have an editable text property.

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Test()
Dim CC As ContentControl
For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
  With CC
    .LockContentControl = True
    .LockContents = False
    Select Case .Type
      Case wdContentControlRichText, wdContentControlText, wdContentControlComboBox, wdContentControlDate
        .Range.Text = ""
      Case wdContentControlDropdownList
        .Type = wdContentControlText
        .Range.Text = ""
        .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
      Case wdContentControlCheckBox: .Checked = False
      Case wdContentControlPicture: .Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete
    End Select
  End With
Next CC
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many type of conent controls all you need is add an if condition to check if content coontrol type is of text

```
Sub Test()
  Dim CC As ContentControl
  For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
      CC.LockContents = False
      If CC.Type = wdContentControlRichText Or CC.Type = wdContentControlText Then
        CC.Range.Text = ""
      End If
  Next CC
End Sub
```